# AngularJS route failed when refresh

Tags: angularjs, spring, routes

After i start the server, it works fine when i click the link to these page. but when i refresh the page it failed, it seems send the route url to server and not found. the backend is spring rest

```
app.config([ '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
            function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
                $routeProvider.when('/k3/test', {
                    controller : 'liantestCtrl',
                    templateUrl : '/views/lian.html'
                })otherwise({
                    redirectTo : '/k3/fu'
                });
            } ]);
```

Error :

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /k3/test. Reason:

   Not Found
Powered by Jetty://
```

do i need any other settings

Comment: you have to configure @ the server too because you are using `html5mode` to `true`. [take a look @ **Server side**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is probably because you have no URL rewriting in place, so the server cannot resolve the requested URL. 
You should add a [rewrite rule](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Rewrite_Handler) to redirect all requests to index.html where the URL will be managed by AngularJS.